# Prevent errors when doing a Webrequest in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, webrequest, webresponse

I receive three errors using the following function:

```
Private Sub readWebpage(ByVal url As String)
    Try
        Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
        If Not resp.ContentType.Contains("text/html") And Not resp.ContentType.Contains("application/xhtml+xml") Then Exit Sub
        Using Str As System.IO.Stream = resp.GetResponseStream
            Using srRead As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
                parseHtml(srRead.ReadToEnd, url)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        Debug.Print(url)
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unable to download content from: " & url)
    End Try
End Sub
```

> The remote server returned an error:
>   (500) Internal Server Error.
>
> The server committed a protocol
>   violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
>
> The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'dmoz.orgsearch'

How would I be able to prevent these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent remote errors. The best you can achieve is catch the exceptions the way you already are.

I would however suggest that you are using an incorrect url - `dmoz.orgsearch` does not exist.

Was this supposed to be: `http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=myquery`?

If the URL you are using is malformed, there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: I use the code in a crawler-like application (not exactly but close enough :P). So somewhere it found the link to `dmoz.orgsearch`. Whether it is correct or not cause it found it dynamically.

Comment: @PeeHaa - I understand that. However, without making the request and getting an exception, you will not know it is malformed.